# What if I take backup and than do partition of drive (shrink and allocate to new one)?

Tags: partitioning, lenovo-laptop, partition-recovery, windows-backup

I just bought a Lenovo G-50-80 series laptop having Windows 10 and there are inbuilt two partition of drive exist

> 1. C:
> 2. D:

I have taken backup of the OS using NTFS by lenovo's provided recovery feature and than I have change the partition I mean I shrink one of the drive and allocate new one (F) in manage-> disk management .

So my question is now what if I recover my data using that backup, Will I lost my data from the drive (F) that was created after taking the backup or what could happen?

Or do I need to take another backup with the newly created drive?

Comment: There isn enough information provided by you to be sure? Any well written programs for backup sould have little problem with what your suggesting as long as the data size is smaller than the hole your trying to return it to. . The OS doesnt care much if you have not shifted folders off to the other partitions, then pulled the partions out from under it.  There is some assumption that you have all this backed up on Another disk (or 2), not just on the one you would be altering   More info that would help the question:  What is the exact os?  What is the backup program? What is the data type?

Comment: @Psycogeek Thank you for the anwer I have updated my question again please go thorugh it and suggest me what to do now?